# Hadoop 2.2: classpath not found excpetion

Tags: tomcat, hadoop, cygwin

I am trying to run hadoop on Window 7, 64 bit with CYGWIN and have followed installation instruction from http://raseshmori.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/install-hadoop-2-0-1-yarn-nextgen/.

I am able to check hadoop version successfully:

```
vgv@IPLCEWKS02820 ~/yarn/hadoop
$ ./bin/hadoop version
Hadoop 2.2.0
Subversion https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1529768
Compiled by hortonmu on 2013-10-07T06:28Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 79e53ce7994d1628b240f09af91e1af4
This command was run using /C:/cygwin64/home/vgv/yarn/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar
```

and my ~/.bashrc is as under:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=$HOME/yarn/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HOME/yarn/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HOME/yarn/hadoop
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HOME/yarn/hadoop
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HOME/yarn/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HOME/yarn/hadoop/etc/hadoop
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_CONF_DIR
```

But, I am unable to format 'namenode'

```
vgv@IPLCEWKS02820 ~/yarn/hadoop
$ ./bin/hadoop namenode -format
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

     18 [main] bash 3948 fork: child -1 - forked process 1284 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000005, errno 11
/home/vgv/yarn/hadoop/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode

vgv@IPLCEWKS02820 ~/yarn/hadoop
$ ./bin/hadoop hdfs namenode -format
Error: Could not find or load main class hdfs
```

Even, I am unable to start HDFS processes:

```
vgv@IPLCEWKS02820 ~/yarn/hadoop
$ ./sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
starting namenode, logging to /home/vgv/yarn/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vgv-namenode-IPLCEWKS02820.out
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value under $HOME variable, by running the following command in console  :

```
# echo $HOME
```

If you get output like :

```
/root
```

OR
    /home/USERNAME

check for the relative paths under ~/.bashrc file.

HTH!!